# How can I fetch only fields from ecto model?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Let say I have a model, like that:

```
defmodule User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :first_name, :string

    belongs_to :role, Role
    has_many :comments, Comment
  end
end
```

User struct will be represented by both associations and fields, like that:

```
model = %User{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
  comments: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded,
  email: "alex@google.com",
  first_name: "alex",
  role: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded
}
```

How can I get map based on this struct with fields only?

Answer (score 25):

Ecto defines [a `__schema__` function](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-reflection) for models. So, you can fetch fields using this function:

```
fields = User.__schema__(:fields)
```

And then use `Map.take/2`

```
Map.take(model, fields)
```